# What are the odds of landing the same number 6 times in a row when there are 9 possible numbers?

Tags: probability

Example: a 9 sided dice - 1-9 are represented

You have 6 rolls of this single dice

What are the odds of landing on the number 6, all 6 rolls?

Back Story: I've been curious about numerology for quite some time. My life path is a 7 and my wife's is an 8. How I got this: all the digits of my birth month, day and year add to a 34. In numerology, you always break down to the single digit so 3+4=7 - thus my 7 life path. My wife's digits add to a 35. 3+5=8. Supposedly you combine you and your spouses numbers together to get a "relationship" number. Thus, 7 + 8 = 15, which breaks down (1+5=6) to a 6.

Since we were married, we've lived in 6 different homes and all 6 addresses break down to a 6, which is sort of blowing my mind and I feel the odds of that are very slim.

Our addresses as follows:

150 (1+5=6)

501 (5+0+1=6)

3210 (3+2+1+0=6)

9906 (9+9+0+6=24, 2+4=6)

6810 (6+8+1=15, 1+5=6)

9735 (9+7+3+5=24, 2+4=6)

Anyway, Numerology is one of those things very hard to explain but over the years I've experienced so many "coincidences" it's hard for me to believe there aren't certain energies associated with numbers. My educated guess is that it's the universal language of the Universe.

Any help with the odds or input on their opinion on energies of numbers, etc would be much appreciated. I never had a real interest in math because I could never get a teacher answer me why I needed to learn advanced mathematics. The answer I got when asked, "Why do I need to learn Algebra?" was met with, "If you want to be an algebra teacher." From that day I had no real interest, but wish I had!

Comment: Have you seen the Kennedy - Lincoln association?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln%E2%80%93Kennedy_coincidences_urban_legend If you consider enough data you can find an amazing amount of correspondences.

Comment: The question in the title doesn't quite match the question in the text.  The text specifies a particular number that is to appear each time, the title does not.

Comment: Numerology is not mathematics. It is not even wrong.

Comment: You didn't have 6 rolls of the die, though. You had dozens, and then picked the ones that formed a nice pattern. Do you really think the numbers of the houses you lived in are the most important part of your relationship?

Answer (score 3):

The probability of that is $(\frac{1}{9})^6$ or $1$ in $531441$ (about one in half a million)

But what are the chances of you coming up with $6$ occurrences of '$6$'? Cognitive psychologists will have to say a few things about that! In fact, I can probably very quickly come up with 6 occurrence of '6' in my own life.

In fact, how many numbers did you try? Did you maybe 'throw out' any of the ones that did not get to $6$? If so, then notice that this is *quite* different from getting $6$ *consecutive* '$6$'s, and the chances of getting  $6$ occurrences of '$6$' will increase significantly. E.g. if you tried this with $12$ numbers, and $6$ of them got to $6$, then the chances of that are:

$${{12}\choose 6} \cdot (\frac{1}{9})^6 \cdot (\frac{8}{9})^6$$

which is about $1$ in $1200$ ... still a very small chance, but not as improbable as the original number, and certainly not as improbable as you thought it was.  And by the way, if you got $6$ occurrences of a '$4$', then you would have been equally 'struck' by the slim chances of that. Or how about $8$ occurrences of '$8$' ... consider all those possible outcomes, and you're probably closer to $1$ in $100$.

Also, was there really not an address before these 6 addresses?  When a sports commentators ever says "and they won 4 out of the last 5 games!", you can bet top dollar that they won 3 out of the last 4 (if it was 4 out of the last 4, the commentator would have said *that*) and 4 out of the last 6 (if it was 5 out of the last 6, the commentator would have said *that*). That is, we tend to notice and report on the peaks and valleys, rather than average trends.

Relatedly, you say you've had many strange coincidences ... so why did you pick this one about the addresses?  Maybe that was the most 'striking' one? Are you like the sports commentator?

Indeed, what other numbers did you try?  You say you're into numerology, so I bet you tried quite a few more. Did you try it with your birthdays, your SSN's, your addresses before you lives together, etc.?  You give me enough data to work on, and I can easily find some strange coincidences. Or, as Aristotle said: "unlikely things are likely to happen" - but then in Greek of course :)

His point was: each specific event may well be very unlikely to occur, but out of all those unlikely events, it is in fact very likely that some of them will occur.

Personal story: it seems that many times I look at a clock it is 11:11. Of course, many times I do not see 11:11, but it feels as if I see 11:11 more frequently than chance would dictate. OK, but consider this: 11:11 stands out as an interesting pattern, but 4:36 does not. Hence, I am more likely to remember the event of seeing 11:11, and everytime I see it again, this gets reinforced, whereas everytime I see 4:36 I just shrug my shoulders and think nothing of it. This is called selective memory.  Also, I am really more likely to see 11:11 than 4:36, even as both pass twice every day: at 4:36am I am usually asleep, but 11:11pm I am often still up ... though maybe looking at the clock as my body starts telling me that it is maybe a good time to sleep. And finally, it's not just 11:11 ... it's also 12:34, and 4:44 that I often see:  it's 'nice' patterns that seem to appear more often than chance dictates.  But if you think of how many sequences I can make into a 'nice' patterns, especially with a good mind for simple arithmetic (e.g. 12:35 is '1+2 =3 and 2+3 =5 ; 12:36 is '1+2 = 3, 1+2+3=6; 12:37 is '1+2=3, 1+2*3=7', etc.), then it turns out there are many more 'nice' patterns than I think there 'ought' to be, i.e. I severely underestimate the chances of 'strange' events happening to me.

Anyway, if you want to take numerology seriously, then rather than looking backward and see which data fits the pattern, try making some predictions, like all good science does.... and don't 'explain away' any deviations by saying 'oh, of course, I should have added the number of children my neighbors have!' when you're 2 short.

Comment: Note OP says "6 times in a row". That seems consecutive to me.

Comment: @MPW Right ... but I am pressing if the OP really found these $6$'s in a row, or whether the OP conveniently skipped or 'forgot' those that did not end up in $6$

Comment: Since being married, we have lived in six different homes. Each of those homes street address break down to a 6 based on numerology rules. I simply thought this was quite interesting and it wasn't planned. Thanks to you who helped satisfy a curiosity itch!